# R cannot resolved ... when built xml code

Tags: android

I create a xml file presentation_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView 
            android:text="..."
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom"                       
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"        
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"                     
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"        
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:src="@drawable/preloaderf1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img6"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img7"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/level"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/proBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:progress="50"         
            android:max="100"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

what is the error ? I built >>> R cannot resolve ?

Layout design is as follows,

[image]

xml file id error ?

Comment: Use pastebin for pasting your codes. Please don't use mediafire for such purpose.

Comment: Post on StackOverflow, when you are on StackOverflow, not paste bin.
Also, you should never be importing R from the android package. This is an error in itself.

Comment: If you are using eclipse expand your res folder and look for red exclamations to find a resource error, fix, rinse, repeat until none are left.  If you don't have any then clean-build

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Project->Clean?

Answer (score 1):

This might possibly be because you are referring an id `@id/bottom` in the other top layouts as `android:layout_above="@id/bottom"` even before it was declared. Don't try to refer ids before they are declared. Check this link which gives more light on this issue:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout

Declare the linear layout with `@id/bottom` just below the linear layout with `@+id/top` and this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first occurance of the id is the one that has to have the "+", whether it is the widget or a reference to the wiidget.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_below="@id/top" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

The above is perfectly valid.   When you get to the "bottom" widget, there you would just use `@id/bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have images in your drawable folder with capital letters or any incorrect format. It causes the loosing of R.java file.

If you can't find where the error is, just restart the eclipse and see console. It shows where the error is.